# "the very best" vs. "by far the best" vs. "much the best"

Tags: meaning, superlative-degree, nuance

What does the following sentence exactly mean?

> He is **the very best** student in our class.

Is it any different in meaning from the following?

> He is **by far the best** student in our class.
>
> He is **much the best** student in our class.

Comment: If you are an English language learner rather than a native speaker or serious linguist, you might find [our sister-site for English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) to be a rather better fit for your questions than the current site, given that our charter here at ELU reads: *“English Language & Usage Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for  **linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts.”***

Answer (score 1):

"He is the very best student" means that there are many excellent students, but he is better than the others.  "He is by far the best student" means that no other student is close in quality to him --it could either mean that he is exceptional, or that the other students are dunces.

"He is much the best student" would probably not be used, since the "much" is ambiguous, and the sentence could be taken as "he is mostly the best student," meaning that much about him is of the best academic quality, but not everything.

Comment: Another usage of _very_ in say "He is the very best student" is purely for emphasis, with very used to emphasise the statement rather than that there is a general level of excellence in the class. Context will probably help. //  There is no confusion with 'He is much the best student' which means the same as 'He is by far the best student', but is rather old-fashioned and formal.